# Trying to setup lambda to access my RDS server on AWS but getting timeouts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I know AWS allows this now and has [instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html) for a manual setup. I'm trying to set this up in a cloudformation though and am running into difficulties. Currently when I try to access my RDS server I am getting `connect ETIMEDOUT` errors.

I have my VPC, Subnets and security groups setup with the following:

```
"VPC": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
  "Properties": {
    "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16",
    "EnableDnsSupport": "false",
    "EnableDnsHostnames": "false",
    "InstanceTenancy": "default",
    "Tags" : [{ "Key": "Name", "Value": { "Ref": "DomainName" } }]
  }
},

"SubnetA": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
  "Properties": {
    "VpcId": { "Ref": "VPC" },
    "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/24",
    "AvailabilityZone": { "Fn::Select": [ "0", { "Fn::GetAZs": { "Ref": "AWS::Region" } }]},
    "Tags" : [{ "Key": "Name", "Value": { "Ref": "DomainName" } }]
  }
},

"SubnetB": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
  "Properties": {
    "VpcId": { "Ref": "VPC" },
    "CidrBlock": "10.0.1.0/24",
    "AvailabilityZone": { "Fn::Select": [ "1", { "Fn::GetAZs": { "Ref": "AWS::Region" } }]},
    "Tags" : [{ "Key": "Name", "Value": { "Ref": "DomainName" } }]
  }
},

"SubnetGroup": {
  "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup",
  "Properties": {
    "DBSubnetGroupDescription": "Database Access",
    "SubnetIds" : [{ "Ref": "SubnetA" }, { "Ref": "SubnetB" }],
    "Tags" : [{ "Key": "Name", "Value": { "Ref": "DomainName" } }]
  }
},

"SecurityGroup": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
  "Properties": {
    "GroupDescription": "Database Access",
    "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"},
    "SecurityGroupIngress" : [{
      "IpProtocol": "tcp",
      "FromPort": "3306",
      "ToPort": "3306",
      "CidrIp": "10.0.0.0/16"
    }],
    "Tags" : [{ "Key": "Name", "Value": { "Ref": "DomainName" } }]
  }
},
```

I don't actually use `SubnetB` but to make `AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup` you need subnets in at least two availability zones.

My RDS database is setup with the VPC and Security group.

```
"Database": {
  "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
  "Properties": {
    "DBName": { "Fn::Join": ["", { "Fn::Split": [".", { "Ref": "DomainName" }]}]},
    "AllocatedStorage": "5",
    "DBInstanceClass": "db.t2.micro",
    "Engine": "MySQL",
    "EngineVersion": "5.5",
    "MasterUsername": { "Ref": "DBUsername" },
    "MasterUserPassword": { "Ref": "DBPassword" },
    "DBSubnetGroupName": { "Ref": "SubnetGroup" },
    "VPCSecurityGroups" : [{ "Fn::GetAtt": [ "SecurityGroup", "GroupId" ] }],
    "Tags" : [{ "Key": "Name", "Value": { "Ref": "DomainName" } }]
  },
  "DeletionPolicy": "Snapshot"
},
```

So I think the database side is correctly in the VPC and able to talk both subnets.

My lambda is setup in the security group and in SubnetA.

```
"LambdaFunctionUpdate": {
  "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
  "Properties": {
    "Code": {
      "ZipFile": "exports.handler = function (event, context) { context.succeed(\"Hello, World!\"); };"
    },
    "Description": "Used to create and or sync database tables to the application models",
    "Handler": "index.handler",
    "MemorySize": 128,
    "Role": { "Fn::GetAtt": ["LambdaExecutionRole", "Arn" ] },
    "Runtime": "nodejs4.3",
    "Timeout": 30,
    "VpcConfig": {
      "SecurityGroupIds": [{ "Fn::GetAtt": ["SecurityGroup", "GroupId"] }],
      "SubnetIds": [{"Ref": "SubnetA"}]
    }
  }
},
```

At the end of everything I'm outputting the database endpoint information.

```
"Outputs": {
  "DatabaseEndpoint": {
    "Value": { "Fn::Join" : [":", [{ "Fn::GetAtt": ["Database", "Endpoint.Address" ] }, { "Fn::GetAtt": ["Database", "Endpoint.Port" ] }]]},
    "Description": "Database endpoint"
  }
}
```

When I run my lambda and try to connect to the RDS server with the endpoint given I get timeout errors.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "connect ETIMEDOUT",
  "errorType": "SequelizeConnectionError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Handshake._callback (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:95:20)",
    "Handshake.Sequence.end (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:86:24)",
    "Protocol.handleNetworkError (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:364:14)",
    "Connection._handleNetworkError (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:428:18)",
    "Connection._handleConnectTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:424:8)",
    "Socket.g (events.js:260:16)",
    "emitNone (events.js:67:13)",
    "Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)",
    "Socket._onTimeout (net.js:318:8)",
    "_runOnTimeout (timers.js:524:11)",
    "_makeTimerTimeout (timers.js:515:3)",
    "Timer.unrefTimeout (timers.js:584:5)"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VPC configuration was incorrect. DNS services can't be turned off.

```
"VPC": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
  "Properties": {
    "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16",
    "EnableDnsSupport": "true",
    "EnableDnsHostnames": "true",
    "InstanceTenancy": "default",
    "Tags" : [{ "Key": "Name", "Value": { "Ref": "DomainName" } }]
  }
},
```